# Como guardar retorno em requisição Ajax em uma variável

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, assincronismo

> Tentei o código seguinte, mas não funciona

```
    function getCategoria(id){
        var categoria;

        $.ajax({
            url: "../control/anuncio/index.php",
            data:{
                 method: 'get_categoria',
                 id_categoria: id
            },
            method: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(retorno){
                 categoria = retorno.categoria;
            }
        });

       return categoria;
    }
```

Comment: da um console.log(retorno), e nos mostrá o resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ajax` é uma função assíncrona, portanto o programa não irá esperar executar o `ajax` para depois dar o retorno da sua variável categoria. Mas para nossa sorte, podemos fazer a função `ajax` ser síncrona adicionando a propriedade `async` como `false`:

```
function getCategoria(id){
    var categoria;

    $.ajax({
        url: "../control/anuncio/index.php",
        data:{
             method: 'get_categoria',
             id_categoria: id
        },
        method: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function(retorno){
             categoria = retorno.categoria;
        }
    });

   return categoria;
}
```

Dessa forma, a linha `return categoria;` só será executada após finalizar a requisição.

Answer (score 2):

O Ajax funciona de forma assíncrona, ou seja, a requisição é enviada e o restante do código continua a ser executado.

Para capturar e exibir o valor do retorno da requisição, é necessário adicionar essas funções dentro do `callback` de sucesso.

```
function getCategoria(id){
    $.ajax({
        url: "../control/anuncio/index.php",
        data:{
             method: 'get_categoria',
             id_categoria: id
        },
        method: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(retorno){
             exibeMensagem(retorno.categoria);
        }
    });
} 

function exibeMensagem(msg) {
    alert(msg);
}
```

Uma outra forma é adicionando a opção `async:false,`. Ex:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "../control/anuncio/index.php",
        async: false,
        data:{
             method: 'get_categoria',
             id_categoria: id
        },
```

Porém há um problema. Os navegadores atuais exibem o alerta:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

O motivo? Em breve isso será removido e você não poderá utiliza-lo. Segundo a própria especificação da API...

> Requisições síncrona está em processo de remoção da plataforma web, pois tem efeitos prejudiciais para a experiência do usuário final.
>
> Os desenvolvedores **não** devem passar falso para o argumento assíncrono quando o objeto global atual é um `Window`. Os usuário são fortemente encorajados a avisar sobre tal uso em ferramentas de desenvolvimento e pode gerar a exceção `InvalidAccessError`

Claro que não irão remover de uma outra para outra, porém o ideal é se adequar o quanto antes. Então o recomendado é você criar uma outra função para tratar o retorno da requisição *(como mostrado no primeiro exemplo)*.